# Callback for Controller.File in MVC after it is done downloading

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller that serve files using the Controller.File

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
{
  return File(fileToDownload.File, "Application/zip", fileToDownload.FileName);
}
```

As I understand the Controller.File encapsulates streaming the file to the end user. So something like this happens...

**request -> controller -> action -> return File -> (Download) -> Download done**

If the file is large and I want to do something after the download is done, is there a way to do this?

******Additional info*********

I want to know whether their download is in progress or completed so I can do something in the server like mark the download as successful similar when you're manually streaming the file, the Response.IsClientConnected will be false if the client is no longer connected.

Comment: You want to do something on the end user's machine ???? :)

Comment: Nope, I want to know whether their download is in progress or completed so I can do something in the server like mark the download as successful similar when you're manually streaming the file, the Response.IsClientConnected will be false if the client is no longer connected.